# Is a polynomial function that is O(e^x) possible?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, big-o-notation

Are there any polynomial functions that are $O(e^x)$? Is this possible?

Comment: Well, $e^x$ is in $O(e^x)$...

Comment: @nirshahar are there any polynomial functions?

Comment: All polynomial functions are $O(e^x)$. Proof is left as an exercise.